# DiscordJS mysql connection stops working after bot has been online for several hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, mysql2

I've had this problem with a discord bot i've made for sometime now. It uses a mysql database and everything works good except for one problem. After the bot has been online for say, 8-10 hours, the mysql database stops sending results. The variable I use to store the results will always return null no matter what command I use. This is immediately fixed upon restarting the bot. Does the connection close automatically after a certain period of inactivity or something?

I'm not sure what part of the code would cause this problem so if you need a specific part of the code for more detail I can provide it.

```
// Opens mysql connection
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'ip',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database_name',
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

This is the code for the connection itself at the start. (Fake values obv)

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Query.onResult (/home/container/index.js:404:35)
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/home/container/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:169:11)
    at Connection.query (/home/container/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:572:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:381:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

and this is the error that happens eventually (undefined, reading length is because its trying to get the length of the result, result.length)

Anyone know a possible cause for this problem?

I haven't tried any specific solution because I'm still pretty new to javascript and the mysql2 package so im not sure what I would go about fixing. Just wanting to know what might cause this problem in the first place.

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` I guess that you are trying to access the length property of an undefined variable,  it seems to be related to a query result `Query.onResult (/home/container/index.js:404:35)`

Comment: Yes, the result of the query is returning as undefined. The problem is that it doesn't return undefined for the first 8 hours or so that the bot is online, then after that time it starts returning undefined.

Comment: why don't you close the connection and reconnect for each query? or just use [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) or [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)

Comment: would using a connection pool suffice for closing the connection and reconnecting? I've tried using sequelize in the past and personally i found using mysql2 a bit easier to understand.